# Auto Complete Google

Tags: html, input, google

O `input`:

```
<div class="input-group" style="width:50%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
                        <input class="form-control" vs-google-autocomplete="autoCompleteOptions"
                               ng-model="address"
                               vs-latitude="latitude"
                               vs-longitude="longitude"
                               vs-city="city"
                               vs-place-id="placeId"
                               name="address" type="text">
                    </div>
```

O **auto-complete-google** funciona normlamente porém quando acessado por **celulares androids** o *auto-complete do google* fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma ideia de como consertar isso? Ou o motivo do bug?

Comment: Posta o código do CSS do input

Comment: @PauloHDSousa nenhum css é aplicado, apenas o CSS do bootstrap que está na "class"

Comment: @PauloHDSousa ?

Comment: Faça um `test` crie um arquivo `html` novo, sem seu código, apenas para saber se não está dando conflito com algum plugin.